# Setting the number of viewable item count in listView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Is there a way to set the viewable item count for a listview? or am I obliged to set the height for the listview?

For instance, I got a list that includes 9 items. I only want 4 of them to appear at first. Then user needs to scroll to see other items.

list_anlam.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_margin="1dp"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/title_popup_hikayeoku" />
      <EditText android:id="@+id/kelime_text"
          android:inputType="text"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />

      <ListView android:id="@+id/list_anlam"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button_sec"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/button_popup_hikayeoku" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml :

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

Where I fill items into listview : HikayeOkuActivity.java is

```
String[] anlamlar = null;
                    anlamlar = MainActivity.dbM.ilkAnlamGetir(selectedText);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,anlamlar);
                    anlamList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(mainLayout, touchedX,touchedY);
```

Comment: there is a default that you can set and a max size ... after that the scroll bar should be enabled automatically

Comment: @Aeshang where exactly can I set these defaults?

Comment: list.setBounds(,,,); in java swt ... what are you using ?

Comment: @Aeshang Not using swt

Comment: what are you unsing ?

Comment: @Aeshang He is using an Android ListView, as stated in the question and the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to get the height of the listview. In your onCreate you do something like:

```
listview.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    height = listView.getHeight();
}
```

In the `getView` method of your adapter you then use the `height` divided by four to set the height of each list item.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    rowView.setMinHeight(height/4);
    return rowView;
}
```

Now this should preferably be done with a ViewHolder, but that's not the topic here.

Comment: It seems there is no short version of what I want. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the height of each view must be 1/4 of the height of your ListView. If you want to support all device resolutions, you have to calculate it. If you need more info about that, add a comment and I will explain it in detail.

Important for details, what kind of Adapter are you using for your ListView?

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail? I am using an ArrayAdapter<String> for my listview.

Comment: Please show the code in your question what you already have (the adapter)

Comment: Some folks suggested that getting the count of the adapter by overriding the getCount() method with like "return 4;" . But that didn't make sense actually.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but..

you could also use an ***android:WEIGHTSUM*** and ***android:WEIGHT*** parameters in your xml layouts. Set android:weightsum=1 for parent view (your ListView) and android:weigth=0.25 for child views (layout of ListView items). In this case you don't have to calculate heights of your viewables.

Comment: Weightsum is a LinearLayout param, not a ListView param.